# 'Resources' is not a member of 'WTApp.My'

Tags: vb.net

I get this error and I can't start my application or edit it.

I've tried deleting the Resources folder and putting everything back and it doesn't help. I also checked my 'Resources.resx' custom tool namespace, and it's fine (uses "My.Resources").

I've tried deleting my images by moving them. It's as if the resx file is hidden from VB.

I really have no idea where to go from here :(

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPtMy.png)

Comment: For future reference, when you add an image and it prompts you with the text "enter image description here", you're supposed to enter the image description there.

Comment: Add resources in the Resources tab for Project Properties. Note that your app is creating (or wants to) a new object whenever the mouse moves. Those images should be loaded into an array so you dont have to worry about disposing them. As is, you app is leaking badly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Application resources are added to Resources.resx file. It create a static property against each added resource while file are stored in a Resources folder physically on the file system however, they are embedded into application on compilation depending.

Because you have deleted the resources(images most likely) from Resources folder but application (Resources.resx) is still referencing to these files.

There are two ways to fix it.
1- Go to application resources TAB and delete all the resources & Added the back.
OR
2- Put all the resources into Resources directory. select all and include them (because you had deleted them once so, they may still present in the directory but are not included in project). if you do not see in folder(from visual studio then make sure to click show All Files button on the solution explorer.

[This shows how to go to Resources TAB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZoPOj.jpg)

[This shows how to include resources which already exists in the folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqyxB.jpg) (got deleted)

Comment: I guess I added two images with default names and it wouldn't let me access the Resources tab.

Comment: I guess I added two images with default names and it wouldn't let me access the Resources tab.

So I went into the resx file and deleted the one that it renamed which did have the same name as a resource which already existed. I removed it's 3 lines of code and refreshed VB and it removed all the errors and now I have only 1 left :)